# Textbox value returns weird code instead of what's inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, character, addition

I found a bit of an issue when I wanted to add a smiley to an existing textbox. The code

```js
 $cnt=$("#comContent").val
 
 $("#addSmiley").click(function() {
  console.log($cnt);
  $cnt = $cnt + ":)";
  console.log($cnt);
 });
```

```css
#comContent {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<textarea id="comContent" cols="70" rows="20"></textarea>
<i style="margin-left: 10px;overflow:visible;cursor:pointer;" id="addSmiley" class="em em-smiley"></i>
```

and basically what I wanted to do is that after a user clicked on an icon of a smiley, the code should add ':)' to the textbox. I added console.log to see why it doesn't add anything. And then I saw this:

```
function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=n.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,n(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":n.isArray(e)&&(e=n.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=n.valHooks[this.type]||n.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=n.valHooks[e.type]||n.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!==(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c?c.replace(gb,""):null==c?"":c)}}:)
```

I thought it was going to be a simple code, but I don't know what's wrong with it, and why it doesn't work

Comment: you are not calling the `val` function you are only making a reference to it, to call the `val` function on the dom element you have to use `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$cnt=$("#comContent").val();
 
 $("#addSmiley").click(function() {
  console.log($cnt);
  $cnt = $cnt + ":)";
  console.log($cnt);
 });
```

```css
#comContent {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<textarea id="comContent" cols="70" rows="20"></textarea>
<i style="margin-left: 10px;overflow:visible;cursor:pointer;" id="addSmiley" class="em em-smiley"></i>
```

Add parenthesis to your .val. Like $cnt=$("#comContent").val();

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

- You're getting only the reference of function `val`

```
$("#comContent").val // This line gets the implementation of function `val`
```

## The solution

- What you really want is the execution of that function, so you need to call it as follow: `$("#comContent").val()`

**Look this code snippet:**

```js
$cnt = $("#comContent").val();

$("#addSmiley").click(function() {
  console.log($cnt);
  $cnt = $cnt + ":)";
  console.log($cnt);
});
```

```css
#comContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<textarea id="comContent" cols="70" rows="20"></textarea>
<i style="margin-left: 10px;overflow:visible;cursor:pointer;" id="addSmiley" class="em em-smiley"></i>
```

See, now you're calling the function `val` and getting the expected value.